# Angular 2: How to pass down a template through a component property?

Tags: javascript, angular

How to pass down a template through a component property in angular 2?

I've only made the first steps:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'tab',
    template: `<div>#!HERE GOES THE HEADER TEMPLATE!#
                <ng-content></ng-content>
              </div>`
})
export class Tab {
    @Input() title: string;
    @Input() headerTemplate:string;
    ...
```

That could be used something like this:

```
<tab [title]="'Some Title'" [header-template]="'<p>{{title}}</p>'">Some Content</tab>
```

That should render:

```
<div><p>Some Title</p>Some Content</div>
```

At this point I'm stuck.

Comment: Can you describe how you're going to use this template in the Tag Component?

Comment: I expect if the Tab Template is something like :
<div>#HERE GOES THE HEADER TEMPLATE#<ng-content></ng-content></div>
, used this way :
<tab [title]="'Some Title'" [header-template]="'<p>{{title}}</p>'">Some Content</tab>
, would be rendered like:
<div><p>Some Title</p>Some Content</div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I’ve checked that someone already has an elegant solution for this question. 
At https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/src/tabs the tab component can receive a template to tab heading. **Great work!**

Checking the code the solution relies on two directives, a tab specific one:  **TabHeading**  and a generic one:**NgTransclude**)

As presented there, the component can be created passing a template:

```
<tab>
    <template tab-heading>Tab 2</template>
    Tab 2 content
</tab>
```

If someone can give a better explanation of that implementation, please do.

Answer (score 8):

Though this question is very old, there are much better solutions available. There is no need to pass a string as a template - that is very limiting. You can create an  element and get its 'TemplateRef' and send that to a component which takes TemplateRef as input. A component can take any number of TemplateRefs as input actually, and you can inject those templates in any number of places.

Note that the 'template' element is deprecated, and the 'ng-template' element should be used in all cases.

So, in a parent component -

```
<ng-template #thisTemplate>You Can put anything here, including other components</ng-template>

 <tab [template]="thisTemplate"></tab>
```

Then in the tabs component from the OP

```
 import { Component, Input, TemplateRef, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core'
```

.... somehwere in its template ....

```
 <div #viewcontainer></div>
```

Down in the component :

```
 @ViewChild('viewcontainer',{read:ViewContainerRef}) viewcontainer : ViewContainerRef;

 @Input() template : TemplateRef<any>;


 ngAfterViewInit() { 
     this.viewcontainer.createEmbeddedView(this.template);
 }
```

Comment: This is a good tip but doesn't completely work on its own. In the `ngAfterViewInit` method I had to make the `createEmbeddedView` call in a `setInterval` function call to constantly check when it's setup right, otherwise there is a timing issue where this is called before the view container itself is set properly.

Answer (score 3):

An method similar to diopside’s but using a container element for projection in the template rather than programmatically:

*parent.component.html*

```
<app-child [template]=“templateRef”></app-child>
<ng-template #templateRef>
  <p>hello, from defined in parent</p>
</ng-template>
```

*child.component.ts*

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet=“templateRef”></ng-container>
```